# LWC Get Combobox Option from custom Object

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am making a combobox and am expecting to get the values from the ID and Name of the custom object. I am getting an error:

> property 'values' of undefined

The Apex: I have tested the SOQL in the dev console and it returned the expected results of Name , ID

```
public with sharing class EventListController {

    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Events2__c[] getAllEvents() {

       return [SELECT Name, Id 
           FROM Events2__c  ];

    }
}
```

The html:

```
<template>
<lightning-card title={valueText}>
    <template if:false={hasResults}></template>
    <div class="slds-card__body_inner">
        <lightning-combobox
            name="progress"
            label="Select the event you want to manage."
            value={value}
            placeholder="Select Event"
            options={eventOptions}
            onchange={handleEventMgrChange} >
        </lightning-combobox>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

And the js in force-app/main/default/lwc/eventSelectPub/eventSelectPub.js:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getEvents from 
'@salesforce/apex/EventListController.getAllEvents';

export default class EventSelectPub extends LightningElement {
@track value = 'inProgress';
valueText = "Select Event";
@wire(getEvents)
eventsList;

get eventOptions() {
    return this.eventsList.data.values;
    // this one works:
    // return [
    //     { label: 'Family', value: 'family' },
    //     { label: 'Friends', value: 'friends' },
    //     { label: 'Other', value: 'other' },
    // ];
}

 handleEventMgrChange(event) {
    this.value = event.detail.value;
    this.valueText = "Event Selected";        
 }
 get hasResults() {
    return (this.eventsList.data.length > 0);
 }
}
```

I get the error message:

> [afterRender threw an error in 'c:eventSelectPub' [Cannot read property 'values' of undefined]]
>   new Aura.externalLibraries()@https://dream-flow-2707.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/5fuxCiO1mNHGdvJphU5ELQ/aura_prod.js:288:363
>   {anonymous}()@https://dream-flow-2707.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/5fuxCiO1mNHGdvJphU5ELQ/aura_prod.js:55:1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is here.

```
get eventOptions() {
    return this.eventsList.data.values;
}
```

`this.eventsList.data` is an array and does not have any values attribute.You can check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex), the array will be returned in data attribute You have to iterate over your eventList and create an array of options that can be used with Combobox.

Something like:

```
get eventOptions() {
    var returnOptions = [];
    if(this.eventsList.data){
        this.eventsList.data.forEach(ele =>{
            returnOptions.push({label:ele.Name , value:ele.Name});
        }); 
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(returnOptions));
    return returnOptions;
}
```

Comment: This does work, great explanation.

Comment: You could have used Array.map, which is more idiomatic in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

@Dan

`lightning-combobox` is expecting the JS-Array to be in the form you mentioned demonstrated that works:

```
 [
    { label: 'Family', value: 'family' },
    { label: 'Friends', value: 'friends' },
    { label: 'Other', value: 'other' },
 ];
```

Any array of JS-Objects with two properties each: `label` & `value`.

Your controller will return an object in the form (most likely) something like:

```
[
   { id: "...", name: "..." },
...
]
```

You should update your controller class to return a DTO (Data-transfer object, a new class defined in apex or converting `Events2__c` to the previous format, or convert it in JavaScript after it's been returned

```
get eventOptions() {
// here - use a iterative loop to convert `this.eventsList.data.values` 
// to a new JS array of objects, 
// Return value should be of form: [ { label: "...", value: "..." },...]
    this.eventsList.data.values;
}
```

Comment: Looks like three paths I need better understanding:   1)   DTO (Data-transfer object, a new class defined in apex or converting Events2__c to the previous format, or convert it in JavaScript after it's been returned. I tried the converting to Javascript and that worked...

Comment: @Dan more like let server-side do extra processing for proper format or let client-side do it for you. I prefer client-side for this as modern devices are very powerful and easily handle these data changes

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, Yes I can to the same conclusion. Not very heavy lifting for the client. Lots to learn in al of this.